# Find a particular column's value that repeats the most in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

So the Table structure is this

```
      CD id        |          Artist id
```

I want to return the artist who has the most CDs, in this case the artist column value that repeats most.

I'm using Mysql so what is the best SQL query to do this?

Comment: Spaces in column names, for shame :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT `Artist id`, COUNT(`CD id`) AS `cd_count`
FROM `Table`
GROUP BY `Artist id`
ORDER BY `cd_count` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'dont use MySQL I translate a similar TSQL and it becomes like this:

```
SELECT ArtistId, count(CDId) AS CDCount FROM Table
GROUP BY ArtistId ORDER BY CdCount DESC LIMIT 1
```

I hope can help you.
Btw: I remove column spaces in my example ok?