# SQL What Value Repeat Most

Tags: mysql, sql, repeat

My English isn't so good, so I'll give an example.

I have an SQL table that looks like this:

```
╔═══╦═════════════╗
║   ║ myColumn    ║
╠═══╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ repeat      ║
║ 2 ║ Foo         ║
║ 2 ║ Foo         ║
║ 3 ║ repeat      ║
║ 3 ║ repeat      ║
╚═══╩═════════════╝
```

I want to get the value that repeat most.

`foo` repeats twice, and `repeat` repeats 3 times, so I want to get the `repeat`.

I use `mysql` engine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a particular column's value that repeats the most in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148115/find-a-particular-columns-value-that-repeats-the-most-in-a-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an aggregation query:

```
select MyColumn, count(*) as NumRepeats
from t
group by MyColumn
order by count(*) desc;
```

Add `limit 1` before the semicolon, if you only want the value that repeats the most.